# How many rows/columns are there in a tkinter Frame?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Using tkinter we can use either `widget.grid(row,col)` or `widget.pack()` to place a widget.

Since `row,col` corresponds to the row/col-index in a given Frame/Window - how do we know how many columns the Frame/Window consists of? E.g if I want to place a widget in the midle or to the very right

Comment: I think you need to keep track of the row and column count as you build the frame.  I don't know of an easy way to determine this value after the fact.

Answer (score 3):

Rows and columns are just concepts, not actual things.  There is effectively an infinite number of rows and columns, all with a width or height of zero until they contain a widget or are configured to have a minimum width or height. From a practical standpoint, there are as many rows and columns as there are pixels in the window.

In reality, the number of rows and columns is entirely up to you. A widget can have a single row and column or it can have several. It all depends on what you add to the window.

A frame starts out with nothing in it, so there are no rows and columns, just empty space. When you add a widget to a row and column, it now has one row and one column plus maybe some empty space. Even if you place your first widget at row 50 and column 20, there is still just one row (50) and one column (20).

There are simple techniques to put something in the middle, or along the right size. For example, because you can define how many columns, you can configure the master to use three columns and the place your widget in the middle column. You can use `columnconfigure` to cause the last column to take up all extra space with the `weight` option. This will move any widgets in the last column to the right edge.

Comment: Im fairly new to tkinter - do you define how many rows/columns a widget, e.g Frame contains or how many it uses? I thought only the latter

Comment: @CutePoison: a frame starts out with zero. When you add a widget to a row and column, it then has one. Add another widget to a different row and column and it now has two.